# Is it bad practice to use a lot of Nullable<T>?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a library that accesses an XML web service API. The XML will often contain integers/decimal values etc. but quite often the field will contain the string "N/A". To accommodate this, I have designed this type of setup:

```
    public decimal? Humidity { get; private set; }
    public decimal? WindChill { get; private set; }
    public int? HeatIndex { get; private set; }
    public decimal? FeelsLike { get; private set; }
    public decimal? Snow { get; private set; }
```

During the XML parsing I check the type and if it is a string I set the type to be null, otherwise set it to the supplied numeric value. Is this a good or bad practice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my experience, when you're trying to represent **optional** value-type properties--like `int` and `decimal`--using `Nullable<T>` is preferable to the alternatives (e.g. selecting sentinel values in the domain of the types, like `-1`).

So in your case, I think your practice is good.  `null` is a sensible way to represent an `N/A` integer.

Comment: You're correct, but make sure you don't do this very often when trying to work with Serializing.